# How is the usage of @classmethod causing difference in outputs?

Tags: python

I was learning about classes and objects in Python when I came across this dilemma. Below are two cases of the same code, one without `@classmethod` and the other with `@classmethod`:

```
#without @classmethod
>>> class Human:  
...     name = "Rounak"  
...     def change_name(self, new_name):  
...             self.name=new_name  
...   
>>> Human().change_name("Agarwal")  
>>> print(Human().name)  
Rounak  

#with @classmethod
>>> class Human:  
...     name = "Rounak"  
...     @classmethod  
...     def change_name(self, new_name):  
...             self.name=new_name  
...   
>>> Human().change_name("Agarwal") 
>>> print(Human().name)  
Agarwal
```

As you can see that when not using `@classmethod`, the name doesn't change from `Rounak` to `Agarwal`. I don't seem to understand how.

I went through the definition of `@classmethod` in the Python documentation and also went through various questions on Stack Overflow that have detailed explanation about the usage of `@classmethod` but I still don't understand how it is causing this difference in output. I am new to Python, so if I am missing some fundamental knowledge, please let me know.

Comment: @halfer Yes, I have learned that as of now. Thanks, for letting me know though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the classmethod changes the name in the class namespace `Human.__dict__`, which is different from the instance's namespace `Human().__dict__`.  Class methods are usually implemented using a different variable name than `self` as the first argument, for this reason:

```
class Human:  
    name = "Rounak"  

    @classmethod  
    def change_name(cls, new_name):  
         cls.name = new_name
```

Note that you are calling `Human()` again within the print call.  Every time you call `Human()` you are creating a new instance, which has its own namespace!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you are using:

```
class Human:  
...     name = "Rounak"
...
```

name is a class attribute, without the `@classmethod` you modify the self, so the instance of the class. Your problem here is that in your function:

```
@classmethod  
def change_name(self, new_name):  
    self.name=new_name
```

You are using `self` as the variable name, but under the hood python is not passing the instance of a class but the class itself, that is why usually it is written as:

```
@classmethod  
def change_name(cls, new_name):  
    cls.name=new_name
```

Resume:

- Normal version modifies class instance
- classmethod version modifies class itself

Comment: When using cls as the first argument, shouldn't it be cls.name=new_name

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `Human()`, you create a new object. If you were to re-use the first object in the `print()` statement, you'd see the *instance attribute* was indeed set to `Agarwal`.

The call to the `classmethod` persists across all subsequently created instances, because it's modifying the *class attribute*.